# Disable or close NERDTree on opening "vim ."

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm basically working in an environment where I sometimes use ctrlp and sometimes nerdtree. But when I start vim using `vim .` it always opens NERDTree. I've tried various .vimrc config commands:

```
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_gui_startup=0
```

But they all don't work. Is there some whay I can disable the NERDTree directory listing when VIM opens? Note, I don't like just using the `vim` command by itself because I'm usually opening VIM when I'm in the application directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netrw plugin opens when vim opens a directory. NerdTree takes over netrw and therefore opens when editing a directory.

`vim .` is equivalent to `:e .`

Just open vim without the `.` and you will be good

Comment: Is it possible to have the end result of opening it with `vim .`? The reason I do this is so I'm in the correct directory for ctrlp and NERDTree of the application directory I am working on.

Comment: Vim will inherit the working directory. There is no need. I guess if you really wanted to you could do something like `vim "+cd ."`